# Which desktop computers have a TPM chip?

Tags: desktop-computer, tpm

My company employs Bitlocker w/ TPM in order to enable Direct Access so that you are always on the company network even when away from work. I want to have a desktop at home which is always connected, but it has to have a TPM chip. Any idea which motherboards/desktops which support this?

Answer (score 10):

A quick Google seach finds a number.  Should not be hard to find. Here is one. [Gigabyte](http://www.gigabyte.com/microsite/44/tech_080818_ultratpm.htm)  As to OEM systems, most ThinkCenter Lenovo systems and Thinkpads have TPM.  I think many HP buisness class systems do as well  Here is one example [HP Desktop](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06b/12454-12454-64287-3328898-3328898-3785404-3810411.html?jumpid=reg_R1002_CAEN)
  The TPM is really quite common.

Comment: A downvote Really?

Comment: ouch... up vote FTW!

Answer (score 0):

I often assemble my own desktops from parts. My current desktop has MSI motherboard, which has JTPM port on it. I purchased and plugged in [Infineon TPM module](https://shop.msicomputer.com/app/storefront/ProductDetail.aspx?ID=1469), and now TPM is functional. I speculate most motherboards do have JTPM ports, all you need to do is look at documentation.